# Running python scripts from shiny server

Tags: r, python-3.x, shiny-server, reticulate

I am attempting to run python scripts in a shiny app deployed on shiny server.

I am calling the following code

```
library(reticulate)
py_install(c('pandas', 'firebase'))

import('pandas')
import('firebase')

source_python("python/Delete_top_node.py")
source_python("python/Delete_user_node.py")
```

Everything works fine locally. When I attempt to deploy though, I get the following error.

**ImportError: No module named pandas**

Even though the logs in shinyapps.io for this application show:

**Installing collected packages: pandas ....**

**Successfully installed pandas-0.24.2**

I have also tried to create a virtual_env to run python but it states that I am not allowed to do this because an evironment has already been created. Thanks for your help!!!